# angular-fullstack heroku deployment Warning: fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: angularjs, heroku, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

Im new to `angular-fullstack` and I was trying to deploy my app to heroku, but I'm getting this `Warning: Build directory "dist" doesn't exist. Nothing to version. Use --force to continue.` error every time I do this command which is `grunt buildcontrol:heroku`

I already have a heroku app setup on herokuapp.com of course and a git remote for it as well.

**UPDATE**

As [@maurycy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2938008/maurycy) pointed out I did `grunt build` but with --force `grunt build --force` I got the `/dist` and then `grunt buildcontrol:heroku` but now I got this `Warning: fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: clearly the grunt task doesnt create the dist directory and doesnt make the actual build, have you tried running `grunt build` before?

Comment: Hi @maurycy I did that now I got this `Warning: fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: It looks like configuration of your grunt task, check documentation for grunt and heroku where you got the gruntfile, maybe you can post your gruntfile on something like pastebin so we can have a look, be sure to remove critical information before doing so

Comment: This is my buildcontrol config on gruntfile `buildcontrol: {
      options: {
        dir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        commit: true,
        push: true,
        connectCommits: false,
        message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
      },
      heroku: {
        options: {
          remote: 'heroku',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      },
      openshift: {
        options: {
          remote: 'openshift',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      }
    },` @maurycy